# Advance to next (multi)characters on a line

Tags: search, cursor-movement, find

To advance to the next/previous character match on a line I can do:

- `f` `<char>`

However, I find myself wanting to match against two characters on that line, for example, something like:

- `f` `='`

Is this possible to do? Or do I need to do a full search at the bottom (starting with `/`). I find the search to be a bit 'out of the way' and prefer using `f`/`F` when I can!

Comment: There is a plugin which does this: [vim-seek](https://github.com/goldfeld/vim-seek); I think there was also another one, but can't recall the name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vim provides the `f`, `t` or `F`, `T` command to jump forward or backward to a character in current line, and you can repeat the action by pressing `,` or `;`. While these commands are useful, they are not powerful enough to be of real value:

- The movement is restricted to current line.
- There are possibly many repetitions since you can only provide one character.

[vim-sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak) solves these two issues neatly. With vim-sneak, you can go anywhere your eyes can see in just four key strokes in most cases, which is one of the most amazing plugins I have ever seen.

After installing this plugin, add the following minimal settings to your configuration:

```
let g:sneak#label = 1
nmap f <Plug>Sneak_s
nmap F <Plug>Sneak_S
```

The above settings will map `f` and `F` to search forward and backward respectively and use the sneak label mode.

For example, if you want to go to the character `i` which is followed by `m`, first press `f`, then press `im`, all occurrences of im will be highlighted and given a label.

Press the character in a label, the cursor will jump to that location, which is really amazing.

Another similar vim plugin is [vim-easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion).

Ref: [precise cursor movement in vim](https://jdhao.github.io/2019/06/26/movement_navigation_inside_nvim/#precise-cursor-movement).

Answer (score 1):

Some plugins make it possible. The one I tried out is called [sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak) and is quite good. Its readme list other similar plugins that you can try